# mongodb - what roles the user to grant access to all databases

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I have created mongouser as testuser with below roles. I want to give access for new databases for this user. what roles the user to grant access to all databases.

db.createUser({ user: "testuser" , pwd: "testuser", roles: ["dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "enableSharding"]});

Answer (score 2):

> I have created mongouser as testuser with below roles. I want to give
>   access for new databases for this user. what roles the user to grant
>   access to all databases.
>
> db.createUser({ user: "testuser" , pwd: "testuser", roles:
>   ["dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "enableSharding"]});

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) MongoDB grants access to data and commands through [role-based authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/#roles) and provides built-in roles that provide the different levels of access commonly needed in a database system. You can additionally create [User-defined roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/#user-defined-roles).

A role grants privileges to perform sets of [actions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#security-user-actions) on defined  [resources](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/resource-document/#resource-document). A given role applies to the database on which it is defined and can grant access down to a collection level of granularity.

**dbAdminAnyDatabase**

Provides the same privileges as **`dbAdmin`** on all databases except local and config.
The role also provides the listDatabases action on the cluster as a whole.

Changed in version `3.4`: Prior to `3.4`,  [dbAdminAnyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdminAnyDatabase) includes local and config databases. To provide [dbAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdmin) privileges on the local database, create a user in the admin database with dbAdmin role in the local database. See also  [clusterManager](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterManager) and [clusterMonitor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterMonitor) role for access to the config and local databases.

For further your ref [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111727/mongo-create-a-user-as-admin-for-any-database-raise-an-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638258/create-superuser-in-mongo) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-built-in-roles/)